# Docker container, Centos, how to telnet

Tags: docker

I have a centOS virtual machine. I have several dockers into and use k8s to coordinate docker containers. When I ssh into one docker container, how to telnet other container, I notice I could ping, but telnet.

Comment: install telnet through RUN command in Dockerfile

Comment: @IvanAracki Thanks for help. But docker file is not maintained by me. How to install it after deployment?

Comment: @user84592 you can create your own dockerfile and use `FROM` to use the main image as your base, then in the docker file install telnet. (reference https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from)

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  Both "ssh into a Docker container" and "telnet to anywhere" are strange things to do.  In a Kubernetes environment _for emergency debugging_ you can use `kubectl exec` but it's not an everyday thing to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand your question correctly, do you meant to say telnet is not found inside the running container? If not then you can install if while building the image itself.

Comment: I could not control docker file, this is maintained by development team, how to install it after deployment?

Comment: Ideally if needed it should be made available in the base image during building itself. You may install it using yum inside the pod however your pods would be short lived anyways and this would need to be done again and again in a running container - not a good idea. Another such inefficient idea would be to do so as part of your entrypoint script. If all you want to do is port-connectivity checks you may want to try `curl`.

Answer (score 2):

Why you need telnet to other container?
if you want to copy files from one container to another container then you can use

`docker cp <containerid>:<path/to/copy> <conatinerid>:<path/to/copy>`

Docker container is like lightweight os that has minimum but necessary requirements 
and telnet is definitely not one of them but still if you want telnet in container and you are using ubuntu image you can install telnet in container with

`apt-get update && apt-get install telnet`

And if you are using another image you can include telnet in a docker file and from that image you can use telnet into container.

Sorry for writing this in answer. Not having reputation for comment 
but i hope you can understand.